# Does $\log(p \#)\approx p$ hold for large $p$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, primorial

This program

```
? for(k=1,9,s=0;forprime(j=1,10^k,s=s+log(j));print(k,"  ",s))
1  5.347107530717468680518589435
2  83.72839039906392294502692284
3  956.2452651200588678124015162
4  9895.991379156987312668949617
5  99685.38926861255083662384712
6  998484.1750256342921339727141
7  9995179.317856311896844315932
8  99987730.01802200438320982241
9  999968978.5775661447989107185
```

calculates the natural logarithms of the primorials $10 \#,100 \#,...,10^9 \#$

The numerical analysis leads to the conjecture $\log(p \#)\approx p$
for large $p$.

- Is it true that $$\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log(p \#)}{p}=1?$$
- If yes, can this result be derived from the prime number theorem?
- Is there a series giving very good approximations of $\log(p \#)$ for
  large $p$, for example $\log(10^{100} \#)$ ?

Comment: We probably don't have asymptotic equality. We have $\log x\# = \vartheta(x) \sim x$, but to have $x\# \sim e^x$, we'd need the error term to tend to $0$. Even if we only look at primes, $p\# \sim e^p$ would require $\vartheta(p) - p \in o(1)$.

Comment: It does look like $\frac{\log p\#}{p}\to 1$, but that's not the same as your conjecture - indeed, your data shows $p\#/\exp(p)$ getting bigger and bigger - it is $exp(10^k-s)$ and $10^k-s$ appears to grow, not shrink to $0$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Thanks for pointing out my fault.

Comment: I have fixed the error.

Comment: It is known that the product of the primes up to $x$ is asymptotic to $e^{(1+o(1))x}$.

Comment: I am not so firm with the Landau-symbols. What does $o(1)$ mean exactly. And does your statement imply my limit ?

Comment: @Peter $o(1)$ means a quantity that tends to zero as $x$ to infinity, yes it does imply your limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One has $\log (p\#)$ is the sum of $\log q$ over all primes up to  $p$. This is basically the [(first) Chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) $\theta(x)$.

It is a well-known reformulation of the Prime Number Theorem that $\theta(x) \sim x$ that is $\theta(x)/ x$ tends to $1$. 
Indeed, frequently a proof of the prime number theorem actually derives this and from it derives the asymptotic for the prime counting function.

Comment: Thank you very much! The wikipedia-article also provides useful bounds.